# Statement.execute(SQL) JDBC java

Tags: java, jdbc

Since the following method returns a boolean, I would like to know how can I get a `ResultSet` out of it if the method returns `true` hence it is a `ResultSet` execute

```
boolean execute(String sql)
            throws SQLException
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using `execute` method, you can get the `resultset(s)` by using : `Statement.getResultSet`. Here are the details from [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/processingsqlstatements.html):

> **execute**: Returns true if the first object that the query returns is a
>   ResultSet object. Use this method if the query could return one or
>   more ResultSet objects. **Retrieve the ResultSet objects returned from
>   the query by repeatedly calling Statement.getResultSet.**

Answer (score 2):

> To execute a query, call an execute method from `Statement` such as the following:
>
> - `execute`: Returns `true` if the first object that the query returns is a `ResultSet` object. Use this method if the query could return one or more `ResultSet` objects. Retrieve the `ResultSet` objects returned from the query by repeatedly calling `Statement.getResultSet`.
> - `executeQuery`: Returns one `ResultSet` object.
> - `executeUpdate`: Returns an integer representing the number of rows affected by the SQL statement. Use this method if you are using `INSERT`, `DELETE`, or `UPDATE` SQL statements.

[**Trail: JDBC Database Access (The Java Tutorials)**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/)

Answer (score 1):

Read the javadoc.

```
getResultSet()
getMoreResults()
```

Answer (score 1):

Call [getResultSet](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html#getResultSet) method of `Statement` object if [execute](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html#execute) returns true.
Accroding to [Statement#execute](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html#execute)

> The execute method executes an SQL statement and indicates the form of the first result. You must then use the methods getResultSet or getUpdateCount to retrieve the result, and getMoreResults to move to any subsequent result(s).